# time() and date() problems after time change (DST - standard)

Tags: php, date, time, dst

In PHP I would like to output an HTML option list containing dates for the next 14 days.

These appointments are always at 18 o'clock:

```
$today_day = date('d');
$today_month = date('m');
$today_year = date('Y');
$date_entry = mktime(18, 00, 00, $today_month, $today_day, $today_year);
$optionsStr = '<select name="date">';
for ($d = 1; $d < 14; $d++) {
    $date_entry_temp = $date_entry+86400*$d;
    $optionsStr .= '<option value="'.$date_entry_temp.'">'.date('d.m.Y', $date_entry_temp).'</option>';
}
$optionsStr .= '</select>';
echo $optionsStr;
```

The user can then choose from one of these dates and submit the form. The chosen timestamp is then inserted into the database.

So I have some entries in my database.

On another page there is a list of current appointments:

```
mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM appointments WHERE date_time = ".time());
```

So at 18 o'clock there should be some output as there are entries in the database for that day. This works perfectly good until the time changes from DST to standard time or vice versa. Then, indeed, is wrong:

The appointments are shown one hour too late or too early respectively.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please stop writing tags in titles. You've done it on many of your 112 questions.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know one is to avoid this. I'm sorry, I should read the guidelines more carefully.

Comment: 18 O'Clock, I'm sure you mean 1800 Hours. (Eighteen Hundred Hours)

Comment: No, I meant what I said: 18 o'clock which is 6pm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

mktime() creates a unix timestamp. A unix time stamp is the number of seconds from January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT +0000. (Greenwich time)

When you set your timezone to "Europe/Berlin", the timezone is either GMT+0100 (in winter) or GMT+0200 (in summer). This means that the Greenwich time of your appointments changes by one hour when you have DST. That means that the time between the first appointment before the change and the next appointment after the change is not 24 hours, but 23 or 25. However, you generate the appointments by adding 86400 seconds = 24 hours.

You can use the DateTime object and the add() method instead. It takes DST changes into account.

```
// create a new date object with todays date
$date = new DateTime();
// set the time to 18:00
$date->setTime(18,0,0);
$optionsStr = '<select name="date">';
for ($i = 0; $i < 14; $i++) {
    // add 1 day
    $date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    $optionsStr .= '<option value="'.$date->format('U').'">'.$date->format('d.m.Y').'</option>';
}
$optionsStr .= '</select>';
echo $optionsStr;
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php for more information.

Answer (score 4):

Your main issue is that you're not working on GMT dates. Here's a colorful post that highlights the resulting pitfalls:

http://derickrethans.nl/storing-date-time-in-database.html

What you should be doing is, store your appointments datetimes at time zone UTC, compare datetimes at time zone UTC, and display datetimes to users in your (ok) or their (ideal) preferred time zone.

Comment: Actually, the original poster already stores time stamps in UTC, and the article you link suggests the opposite: Store times in local time together with the time zone. (Where by "local" I mean "at the location of the event". Usually events are at a specific time in a specific place, not at a specific greenwich time)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have a problem with timezones: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html
I would get the time selected, convert from your local time to UTC and then put it in the database. If you read it out, convert back from UTC to your localtime.

Comment: Since I use INT(10) columns for my timestamps, there should be no problem with timezones, right? MySQL can't know that this is a timestamp, so the error must be in PHP.

Comment: This doesn't make calculating more easy, by the way.

Answer (score -1):

When relying on the time, please make sure that you always SET A TIMEZONE, either in your php.ini or in your code.  And there's not a whole lot you can do about your database entries, if you sort them by time or date they will end up being interleaved due to the new date being before the date of your last entry prior to the timechange.

Comment: I ALWAYS set the time zone in my code using date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin'). And there should be no leap or overlap since as the time in the timestamp is always continuous.